# Is this optimization in g++ desirable?

Tags: c++, g++

I came across a (for me) unexpected behavior of g++ (v 10.2.1). Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

int f(int x) {
  if(x==0) {
    std::cout << "I am here" << std::endl;
    return 5;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int x = f(atoi(argv[1]));

  std::cout << x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I am aware that the code does not make much sense, since f doesn't return a value if x is not 0. When I compile with `g++ -Wall -O3 -DNDBUG -o bla bla.cpp`, the compiler also warns me about that, naturally. If I run the program anyway, the following happens:

```
$ ./bla 0
I am here
5
$ ./bla 1
I am here
5
$ ./bla 2
I am here
5
$ ./bla 3
I am here
5
```

I get it - the compiler sees that the only possible return is within the if-statement, so it removes the if statement. However, it took me hours to understand that in my actual (non-minimal) code: my function f had also an else-branch, but I commented it out for the purpose of testing a new feature, and then I got weird behavior because of this effect.

My question is whether this is a justifiable optimization or should rather considered as a bug in the compiler?

**Edit**: Thanks for the fast answers. Yes, as I said, I got the warning, too. I agree that one should take warnings seriously. But just to provide an example that is closer to what I actually had: I even ignore the return value in the function that calls f - the main "output" of the function is passed by reference, and the actual output is more of an additional value. So my (wrong) thinking was that it does not matter if the code returns a nonsense value as I won't need it (again, for testing purposes). I still find it strange that the example below changes it behavior if I replace "int f.." with "void f", and "return 5" with "return".

```
#include <iostream>

int f(int x,int& z) {
  if(x==0) {
    std::cout << "I am here" << std::endl;
    z=7;
    return 5;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int z=1;

  f(atoi(argv[1]),z);

  std::cout << z << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
$ ./bla 0
I am here
7
$ ./bla 1
I am here
7
$ ./bla 2
I am here
7
$ ./bla 3
I am here
7
```

**Final edit**: Thanks for the discussion. To summarize (if anyone reads this later): I thought that with a missing return at the end, just the return value of the function is undefined (which would be ok in the extended example). But in fact, the whole behavior of the function is undefined, which is much more than that.

Comment: Not only doesn't it make much sense, it also have *undefined behavior*. Your function `f` *promises* to return an `int` value. But there are paths through the function which doesn't do that, leading to the mentioned undefined behavior. If the compiler doesn't already warn about this, then enable more warnings. And treat warnings as errors. It's definitely not a compiler bug, if your code have UB then the compiler is basically allowed to do what it wants.

Comment: Your code has _undefined behavior_. You shouldn't expect any reasonable results.

Comment: Does not even compile without warnings : https://godbolt.org/z/x74T77oqq. And the warning even shows your problem. Point of learning of the day, NEVER ignore the compiler warnings and make sure your code compiles without them.

Comment: This is definitely not a compiler bug. The compiler can legally assume you never call the function with an argument other than 0 and greatly simplifies the resulting executable accordingly. If you break t hat assumption, then you made a mistake and are at fault.

Comment: *I came across a (for me) unexpected behavior*  What behavior did you expect?  Why do you expect that behavior?  In what way does the behavior observed differ from the behavior you expected?  I recommend enabling compiler warnings, and treating warnings-as-errors, and enabling sanitizers.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer.

Comment: @mike My answer is the same as before your edited question. You simply can't expect any particular behavior from a program with undefined behavior. Also note that UB can "time travel" and show its ugly face even before you think that the offending part of the code has been executed.

Comment: I guess my expectation was that if a function that promises to return an int reaches its end without return, it returns an int value with undefined content (that is, uninitialized). At least I expected that the compiler respects the control flow that I have specified because it cannot know about the side effects of the function.

Comment: Here is a Standard quote for you [`[stmt.return #4]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#4)  _"...Otherwise, flowing off the end of a function that is neither main ([basic.start.main]) nor a coroutine ([dcl.fct.def.coroutine]) results in __undefined behavior__...."_  The compiler respected everything - it is allow to assume the code does not contain UB. Therefore `f` must always be called with `x==0` (as you the programmer would not intentionally invoke UB); therefore the `if` test can be optimised away.

Comment: @mike All such expectations are wrong when you've entered the land of undefined behavior. _"it cannot know about the side effects of the function"_ - I don't understand that part. Everything is known to the compiler except the values of `volatile`s. It's just that a program with UB doesn't map well into the abstract machine.

Comment: Heed the warnings. It's as simple as that.

Comment: A funny variation: I added `printf("bye!");` after the `if { ... }`, and now I get `bye!` printed on the console and then `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_cast'`. It looks like the compiler sees `printf()` as an external function, so UB happens only if/when `printf()` returns, which it does eventually, but it cannot longer assume that `x==0` every time.

Comment: All you can do with Undefined Behaviour is to remove it.  Trying to reason about UB is pointless as the name of the behaviour suggests.

Comment: *I guess my expectation was that if a function that promises to return an int reaches its end without return, it returns an int value with undefined content (that is, uninitialized).*  What value does undefined content (or uninitialized) have?  If I have all my sanitizers enabled (which slow down the program tremendously), uninitialized variables have the behavior of faulting the program with an abnormal termination if the uninitialized variable is read from.  If an uninitialized variable can have any value, what's wrong with `5`?

Comment: @Eljay It's not so much the return value, it is that the if-branch is executed although the if-condition is violated (and this could have side-effects). The example in my edit does never look at the variable returned by the function, but the fact that the return value might be uninitialized is enough to render the entire behavior of the program undefined.

Comment: The way the code was written, the if-branch **must** be executed, and the if-condition **cannot** be violated.  The compiler will warn about this situation, if warnings are enabled.  (Compilers are not required to warn about this problem, but all the compilers I use will warn about it because it is a common programming mistake.)

Comment: @mike That's correct. Any UB anywhere in the program makes the behaviour of the entire program undefined. The point though is that this fact allows the optimizer to assume a well defined program (because it doesn't have to make a program with undefined behaviour behave in any particular way), and in turn this allows the optimizer to be much more effective.

Comment: @Eljay You will hopefully agree with me that it's not entirely clear that the condition cannot be violated. In my interpretation of what a program does, if I call a function f with argument x, I would expect that the code is executed that is specified in the body of f, with x being the passed value. And if that value is 3 and the first line in the body is "if(x==0)", I would believe that this evaluated to false. Perhaps my viewpoint is naive, but I am also not a total beginner in programming and I survived so far with this view.

Comment: @mike Your view is incorrect, and it's a fact that compilers have got a lot more aggressive in recent years in their optimization. There are some decent articles on this on the internet, I'll see if I can find a link. [This one](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633) for example.

Comment: Also, the compiler warns me " warning: control reaches end of non-void function", which is not the same as saying: "warning: if-clause is necessarily evaluating to true". The warning makes me believe that there is the possibility of reaching the end of the function during the execution without a return value which is the opposite of what you say

Comment: Of course there is the possibility of reaching the end of the function. The behaviour is **undefined**. The compiler isn't forced to optimize away the if statement, it's just allowed to do so.

Comment: *You will hopefully agree with me that it's not entirely clear that the condition cannot be violated.*  Quite the contrary, it is entirely clear **to the compiler** that the condition **cannot** be violated.  If warnings are enabled, the compiler will warn that this looks like a mistake/oversight by saying "warning: control reaches end of non-void function".  I usually solve this situation by putting in a `throw "cannot ever happen";` (yes, a string literal) at the end of the function that would otherwise fall off with undefined behavior, to document the situation for the next developer.

Comment: @john Yes, I referred to Elijay's answer that the if-condition **must** be executed. I do understand that the compiler can do basically whatever it wants as the behavior is undefined and that my viewpoint is too naive for recent compilers.
I would be happy about literature points indeed. I am still hoping my viewpoint is a good and practical model for reality **if you take compiler warnings into account**. It seems so, because I am able to write code that seems to do what it should usually. But I am happy to upgrade my view to a better model if there is one.

Comment: I think rather than "the compiler is allowed to assume `x==0` is true", it might be more helpful to think "the compiler has the discretion to do whatever the hell it wants when `x==0` is false". If `x==0` is false, you fail to return a value from a value-returning function and so the behavior is undefined. The compiler can choose any behavior it wants. It chooses "the same behavior I would've produced if `x==0` had been true".

Answer (score 13):

> My question is whether this is a justifiable optimization or should rather considered as a bug in the compiler?

It's justifiable. Compilers are allowed to assume that your program is written in such a way that undefined behavior doesn't occur and they are allowed to make optimizations based on that assumption.

If your program doesn't live up to it, the result can be very confusing, but that's the cost you'll have to pay in order to get good optimizations quickly when creating programs *with* defined behavior.

Comment: I'd suggest changing "undefined behavior doesn't exist" to "undefined behavior doesn't occur". Since such optimizations rely on the freedom granted by Undefined Behavior, it seems to me like they have to at least assume it exists but "never happens".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux UB anywhere in the program makes the whole program have UB right from the start though. The running program doesn't have to enter the section where your code was written in such a way that it makes the program have UB. It can time travel and show up anywhere, so I'm not sure about the suggested edit.

Comment: *"UB anywhere in the program makes the whole program have UB right from the start though."* The program is only UB as a whole from the start if UB is always unavoidable from the start. It's only UB (program-wide) if execution would enter a branch from which UB becomes unavoidable. The code shown is fine if you change the call to `f` to always pass 0. The compiler can only assume that such a branch is never entered. The program as a whole is correct, but has the implicit precondition that `argv[1]` has to be 0.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Hmm, the standard often talks in terms of _a program that defines X has undefined behaviour_ without specifying that X actually has to be used for the program to have UB. Perhaps there are cases I'm unaware of though. Need to read  up :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo [\[intro.compliance.genera #(2.2)\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance.general#2.2) _"...If a program contains a violation of a rule for which no diagnostic is required, this document places no requirement on implementations with respect to that program..."_

Comment: *"Otherwise, flowing off the end of a function that is neither main ([basic.start.main]) nor a coroutine ([dcl.fct.def.coroutine]) results in undefined behavior."* `f` is only conditionally Undefined Behavior. If the condition isn't met, the behaviour of the program has to be correct and isn't UB. It isn't UB for a function to potentially flow off the end. It is UB only if it would. Because running `./bla 0` wouldn't cause the function to flow off the end, the program is well defined in that case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Good point. I'll update

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes, that's the general UB I think of. Hmmm.... I changed it to "occur" for now though.